# How to fix boot message [RAID partition] not ready yet?

Tags: boot, raid, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mdadm: breaks boot due to “is not ready yet or not present” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20857/mdadm-breaks-boot-due-to-is-not-ready-yet-or-not-present-error)

I've got a RAID 5 setup for my `/home` partition. Every two to three boots my hdisks don't seem to be ready in time and my PC hangs saying that `/home` isn't ready yet.

I then have to manually activate it by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and typing **dmraid -ay**.
 This *always* activates the `/home` partition.

How can I tell Ubuntu to wait longer if my home-dir couldn't be mounted yet?

Comment: Are you sure you are using dmraid?  Because it does not support raid5.  Unless you need to dual boot with windows, fakeraid should be avoided.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20857/mdadm-breaks-boot-due-to-is-not-ready-yet-or-not-present-error).